# AWS - API keys available on the Serverless Offline framework?

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-framework-offline

I use **Serverless Offline** to develop a Web project.

I need of **API Keys** to access to resource on **Serverless** **AWS Lamda**.

I have a serverless.yml with my *service* and my *provider*.

In **Postman**, I access to my route (*http://127.0.0.1:3333/segments/UUID/test*), and I haven't any error (*as Forbidden message*), the Lambda is executed...

```
test:
  handler: src/Api/segment.test
  events:
    - http:
        path: segments/{segmentUuid}/test
        method: post
        request:
          parameters:
            paths:
              segmentUuid: true
        private: true
```

The route in question is not protected by private.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline#token-authorizers

> Serverless-offline will emulate the behaviour of APIG and create a
>   random token that's printed on the screen. With this token you can
>   access your private methods adding x-api-key: generatedToken to your
>   request header. All api keys will share the same token. To specify a
>   custom token use the --apiKey cli option.

Command will look like this:

```
sls offline --apiKey any-pregenerated-key
```

Answer (score 2):

For local dev use this inside serverless.yml:

```
custom:
  serverless-offline:
    apiKey: 'your-key-here'
```

Or this inside serverless.ts:

```
 custom: {
    'serverless-offline': {
      apiKey: 'your-key-here',
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Given latest changes this configuration worked for me with serverless offline:

```
  provider: {
    name: 'aws',
    region: region,
    runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
    stage: stage,
    apiGateway:{
      apiKeys: [{
        name: 'test name',
        value: 'sadasfasdasdasdasdafasdasasd'
      }],
    },
  },
```

https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/963

Answer (score 0):

[serverless-offline](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline) removed `--apiKey` as a cli parameter as part of [v11.0.0](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/releases/tag/v11.0.0). The documentation on https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline is currently out of date, "To specify a custom token use the --apiKey cli option." needs to be removed.

> MIGRATION: if you want to specify the apiKey value yourself, please define it under provider.apiGateway.apiKeys in the serverless config

There's a discussion occurring in issue [issues/1608](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/1608); dnalborczyk's response should provide more insight: https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/1608#issuecomment-1306200311.